# Calculating distance for multiple 3d points

Tags: c#

I did do some searching around before asking this, but how can I determine given a collection of coordinates, which ones are within range of one another?

if I had an set of coordinates

I know I can do something like:

```
float[] point1 = new float[3] {756.0,26.0,-1410.0};
float[] point2 = new float[3] {752.0,28.0,-1391.0};
float[] point3 = new float[3] {552.0,28.0,12.0};
float[] point4 = new float[3] {668.0,29.0,12.0};
float[] point5 = new float[3] {869.0,35.0,13.0};
float[] point6 = new float[3] {768.0,29.0,-1407.0};
float[] point7 = new float[3] {769.0,35.0,-1393.0};
```

and then compare one set of coordinates to another, but what I'm hoping to do is have a List of coordinate, and I want to display the ones that are ONLY within a certain range of one another.  I'm just not sure how to do more than 1 at a time.

```
List<float[]> Positions = new List<float[]>();
float[] location = new float[3] { entity.X, entity.Y, entity.Z }
Postions.Add(location)
... loop thru and add all values ...

            int rSquare = 25;  //minimum distance I want to be less than
            int x0 = 10, y0 = 10, z0 = 10;  //placeholder because I dont know what I'm comparing against
            var res = locations
                .Select(tmp =>
                {
                    return new
                    {
                        x = tmp[0],
                        y = tmp[1],
                        z = tmp[2]
                    };
                })
                .Where(p => (p.x - x0) * (p.x - x0) + (p.y - y0) * (p.y - y0) + (p.z - z0) * (p.z - z0) < rSquare)  
                .ToList();
```

and that would give me one coordinate compared to another and return all that had a distance < 25.  How can I compare any given set of coordinates to any other given set within the Positions list?  The 'placeholder' is just there to give me something to go against but I'm hoping there is an easier way than comparing them all against themselves one at a time.

thanks

edit in response: I expect that I would get back any of the coordinates that fall within the desired distance from one another.  In this case, from the given 7 points, I would expect to see the values (or some representation there of) of 1,2,6 and 7 since they are all within 25 of each other.  The values for 3,4,5 are well distanced from anything else so I wouldn't want to see them.  I gave 7 values but the list that I ultimately have may have hundreds of x/y/z locations I want to compare.

Comment: It really depends - what do you want to have returned if you have 10 coordinates, in a line, equally spaced, each 24 units apart?

Comment: @ReedCopsey You mean 4 units apart, since OP is looking at the square of the distance.

Comment: @Teepeemm No - I meant 24, given the OP's  "return all that had a distance < 25"

Comment: The easiest way to speed up a 3D search is spatial subdivision, like a KDTree or OcTree.  You still have to do the comparison for each point but if you look at KdTrees in particular there are ways of doing a nearest neighbor search using a bounding box or sphere of some radius R.

Comment: Again - Given your edit, it's unclear - what should the result be if you had 10 coordinates, 24 units apart, in a perfect line?  Any 2 (next to each other) are within 25 of each other, but no 3 are...

Comment: There are options - do you want the points with a distance of the centroid? (That would remove outliers, for example)

Comment: I really just care if one given location is near any other given location.  10 coordinates, 24 apart, I would expect all 10 items to show up in the list, not because 1 is near 10 but because any given item is within range of any other given item.
@Jerdak -I'll look into what the KDTree can do, not familiar off top of head

Comment: @ChristopherKlein I wrote a C# KDTree [awhile back](https://github.com/jerdak/kdtree2) that might quickly get you what you need.  It's based off old C++ code so it won't look as nice as LINQ.  `Vector3` is equivalent to your `float[3]`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force approach could just be:

```
 // Given a distance function:
 double DistSq(float[] point1, float[] point2)
 {
      return (point1[0] - point2[0]) * (point1[0] - point2[0]) 
      + (point1[1] - point2[1]) * (point1[1] - point2[1]) 
      + (point1[2] - point2[2]) * (point1[2] - point2[2]); 
 }
```

You can do:

```
 distance = 5; // How far apart can 2 points be...
 double distSq = distance * distance;
 var pointsWithoutOutliers = Positions.Where(p => Positions.Any(o => !Object.ReferenceEquals(o,p) && DistSq(p,0)<distSq));
```

Comment: brute force works for now.  Functional first, then I can worry about making it pretty.  Takes me 20min to scan thru my source data to come up with my collection of 1200 points that takes nearly 0 time to process so I'd call it a win.  thanks!